# jQuery and OpenLayers matching theme

Tags: css, jquery-ui, themes, openlayers

## Background

Using jQuery widgets and OpenLayers widgets on the same web page.

## Problem

jQuery has [Theme Roller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) while OpenLayers has its [default theme](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/theme/). This results in:

[image]

The toolkit controls have different colours. This can be remedied by customizing either [OpenLayers](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/doc/customization) or [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Theming/ThemeSwitcher) to match the other, but I'd rather not re-invent the wheel if possible. For example:

- http://dev.openlayers.org/sandbox/itranga/openlayers/theme/css/jquery/
- http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/ticket/1800
- https://github.com/developmentseed/openlayers_themes

## Question

Where can I find themes for **OpenLayers 2.12** and **jQuery UI 1.8.18** (that are freely available) that align their colour schemes?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/**
 * Colour customizations for jQuery and OpenLayers widgets.
 */
.ui-dialog-titlebar, div.olControlZoom a {
  background: #0065bd !important;
}
```

You can use FireDebug (or equivalent) to inspect the UI elements. From there, change the colours of the UI elements with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

1. Skip adding usual/default controls to Map object
2. Create **DIV** layer which is styled with zIndex ~ 4000 to be above any map object + position absolute to be fixed on screen
3. Create control jQuery buttons on that layer
4. Catch click events of those buttons and control appropriately map through its Map object

Look at examples, there's jQueryMobile example, which uses jQueryMobile buttons, thus the same  task.